# Why is the download interrupted when i call chrome.downloads.download method with enabled "Ask where to save each file before downloading" option

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, save-as

I'm writing Chrome extension that saves some files using `chrome.downloads.download` method. I call it from my `background.js` and it works fine unless "Ask where to save each file before downloading" option of browser is enabled or `saveAs` option is `true`.

This is `background.js` which reproduces this problem:

```
chrome.downloads.download({
  url: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
  saveAs: false
}, (itemId) => {
  chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener((delta) => {
    if (itemId === delta.id) {
      console.log(delta) 
    }      
  })  
})
```

It downloads google logo when `saveAs` is `false`. In console i can see events first with status `in_progress` then with status `complete`. But if i set `saveAs` to `true`, there will be event with status `iterrupted` and error `USER_CANCELED`. Chrome doesn't open "Save as" dialog for some reason i don't understand, even if "Ask where to save each file before downloading" is enabled. More to it if "Ask where to save each file before downloading" is enabled download will be interrupted regardless of the `saveAs` value.

Chrome documentation describes `saveAs` option: "Use a file-chooser to allow the user to select a filename regardless of whether `filename` is set or already exists". But for me it doesn't work regardless of the value of `filename` option. Am i missing something?

The Chrome version is the last as of today (Version 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and manifest version is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium Version 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit)
still has this bug.

I encountered it in a slightly different context:
[chrome.downloads.download() to d/l a file packaged with the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73479053/chrome-downloads-download-to-d-l-a-file-packaged-with-the-extension)

The results are just like you described, except for the NETWORK_FAILED error, but that's a different problem.

ask = "Ask where to save each file before downloading"

| ask | saveAs | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no | false | NETWORK_FAILED |
| no | true | USER_CANCELED |
| yes | false | USER_CANCELED |
| yes | true | USER_CANCELED |