# chrome.downloads.download() to d/l a file packaged with an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, download

System:

- Manjaro Linux
- Chromium Version 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit)

When the user clicks on this MV3 extension's action, it tries to download the file /text/Test.txt (packaged with the extension) to the Downloads directory:

https://github.com/GrippenDynamik/Download_Extension_File_MV3

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Download Extension File MV3",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Download Extension File MV3"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "downloads"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
function onChanged(downloadDelta) {
    console.log("MV3", "b) onChanged", "downloadDelta", downloadDelta);
}

async function onCreated(downloadItem) {
    console.log("MV3", "a) onCreated", "downloadItem", downloadItem);
}

function onClicked(tab, onClickData) {
    chrome.downloads.download({
        conflictAction: "overwrite",
        filename: "Test.txt",
        saveAs: false,
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("text/Test.txt"),
    });
}

chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(onChanged);
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(onCreated);
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(onClicked);
```

/text/Test.txt

```
This is a test.
```

Results:

- chrome.downloads.onCreated doesn't report any errors.
- chrome.downloads.onChanged reports NETWORK_FAILED (and nothing else)

Am I doing something wrong, or it is not possible to download files packaged with an extension?

I know that I can

1. fetch() the file
2. turn the response into a data URL
3. download the data URL

But it would be nice if I could skip steps 1 and 2.
Simpler is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is MV3, as usual.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1224027&q=downloads.download&can=2

"it doesn't work with chrome.downloads.download which doesn't support chrome-extension:// scheme"

I don't know if this is by design, or just another MV3 bug.

It works perfectly in MV2:

https://github.com/GrippenDynamik/Download_Extension_File_MV2

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Download Extension File MV2",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Download Extension File MV2"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "downloads"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
function onChanged(downloadDelta) {
    console.log("MV2", "b) onChanged", "downloadDelta", downloadDelta);
}

async function onCreated(downloadItem) {
    console.log("MV2", "a) onCreated", "downloadItem", downloadItem);
}

function onClicked(tab, onClickData) {
    chrome.downloads.download({
        conflictAction: "overwrite",
        filename: "Test.txt",
        saveAs: false,
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("text/Test.txt"),
    });
}

chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(onChanged);
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(onCreated);
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(onClicked);
```

/text/Test.txt

```
This is a test.
```

Comment: Your use case seems to be a different bug, much simpler to fix, please report it separately.

Comment: Reported as https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1357326